# How to add and connect a jsp page to a controller in springboot with STS 4.2.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have created a springboot app with maven and added a controller here

```
package ml.developer45.boot.ctrl;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Controller
public class MainCtrl {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello()
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

this is my main class with springapplication.run method

```
package ml.developer45.boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ml.developer45</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

and this is my application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

this is the console output with the no mapping for GET  /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp error

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:   -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-05-03 17:40:36.936  INFO 21051 --- [           main] ml.developer45.boot.DemoApplication      : Starting DemoApplication on 45davy-PC with PID 21051 (/home/davy/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.2.1.RELEASE/demo/target/classes started by davy in /home/davy/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.2.1.RELEASE/demo)
2019-05-03 17:40:36.941  INFO 21051 --- [           main] ml.developer45.boot.DemoApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-03 17:40:43.804  INFO 21051 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-05-03 17:40:43.890  INFO 21051 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-05-03 17:40:43.890  INFO 21051 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-05-03 17:40:44.085  INFO 21051 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-05-03 17:40:44.085  INFO 21051 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7050 ms
2019-05-03 17:40:44.814  INFO 21051 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-03 17:40:45.200  INFO 21051 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-05-03 17:40:45.208  INFO 21051 --- [           main] ml.developer45.boot.DemoApplication      : Started DemoApplication in 8.862 seconds (JVM running for 9.429)
2019-05-03 17:40:55.213  INFO 21051 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-05-03 17:40:55.213  INFO 21051 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-05-03 17:40:55.222  INFO 21051 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
2019-05-03 17:40:55.289  WARN 21051 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
2019-05-03 17:40:56.020  WARN 21051 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
```

I am trying to render a jsp page within the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views folder from my controller but it keep on failing i  even change the packaging to war from jar but it also failed!!
Help please!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've got a solution, i added a dependency to the tomcat-embed-jasper

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```